# What are tag name spaces?

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer, terminology

The C standard says:

> **7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**
>   All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and **tag name spaces**.

What are "tag name spaces"?

Is the following a tagged name space?

```
struct T{};
```

Is it just the type name of a struct?
Does this terminology carry over into C++?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/name_space

Comment: 6.2.3 talks about "tag name spaces"

Comment: These are 'ordinary' namespace and 'tag-name' namespace (the T in struct T {} is a 'tag-name'). C++ has no 'tag-names'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/name_space):

> C allows more than one declaration for the same identifier to be in scope simultaneously if these identifiers belong to different categories, called name spaces:
>
> 1. Label name space: all identifiers declared as labels.
> 2. **Tag names**: all identifiers declared as names of structs, unions and enumerated types. Note that all three kinds of tags share one name space.
> 3. Member names: all identifiers declared as members of any one struct or union. Every struct and union introduces its own name space of this kind.
> 4. All other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers to distinguish from (1-3) (function names, object names, typedef names, enumeration constants).

So, `T` is the name of a struct and in the same namespace as other “tags”, but not in the same namespace as, say, labels. I.e., you could have a label named `T` in the same scope.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this terminology carry over into C++?

No. "Tag names" are not mentioned in the C++ standard except for in the informative annex `C++ and ISO C` where tag names are discussed in the context of C.